# How to get GPU load in percentage and GPU temperature on AMD video cards

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, amd-gpu, ati

Anyone know how get GPU load (in percentage) and GPU temperature on Radeon video cards using some API from some AMD SDK? It's looks like AGS SDK doesn't have needed API. For example NVIDIA has NVAPI, but what about AMD? Looking for solution on Windows platform

Answer (score 2):

Got answer on the AMD forum.
For getting information about GPU temperature and GPU load **ADL sdk** can be used
https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/display-library .

Sample Overdrive_Sample.cpp (https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/display-library/blob/master/Sample/Overdrive/Overdrive_Sample.cpp) has example how to get requirement values from structures **ADLPMActivity** and **ADLTemperature**.

P.S. There is question at the AMD forum about usage this api
https://community.amd.com/thread/230246